# How can I optimise the creation of subsets?

Tags: performance-tuning, combinatorics, subset

I have a list of 21 elements from which I have obtained possible combinations of minimum 3 and up to 10 elements using the `Subsets` function as follows:

```
Elements=RandomReal[1, 21];
Combinations=Subsets[Elements,{3,10}];
```

For simplicity's sake I have made the list of elements in this example a vector of 21 random reals. In reality, each element in my list is in itself a vector of length = ~60.

The elements in my list belong to 3 separate groups, and I need to ensure that the combinations contain at least one element from each group. I have done this in the following manner:

```
Group1 = Elements[[1 ;; 7]];
Group2 = Elements[[8 ;; 14]];
Group3 = Elements[[15 ;; 21]];

NewCombinations = {};
i = 1;
For[i = 1, i <= Length[Combinations], i++,
 If[ContainsAny[Combinations[[i]], Group1] &&
    ContainsAny[Combinations[[i]], Group2] &&
    ContainsAny[Combinations[[i]], Group3],
   AppendTo[NewCombinations, Combinations[[i]]]
   ];
 ];
```

However, because the total possible number of subsets from 3 to 10 elements of a list of 21 elements (i.e. `Length[Combinations]`) is 1,048,344, and this way of creating new combinations includes a `For` cycle with 3 nested `If` cycles, the evaluation is taking forever.

Is there a way of simplifying or optimising the subroutine that calculates 'NewCombinations' to make it faster?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
elements = RandomReal[1, 21];
combinations = Subsets[elements, {3, 10}];
groups = Partition[elements, 7];
```

This took about 11 sec:

```
Timing[ingroups = 
  Length /@ (Table[
       Intersection[g, #] /. {} -> Nothing, {g, groups}] & /@ 
     combinations);
 pos = Position[ingroups, 3];
 answer = Extract[combinations, pos];]
```

> {10.7969, Null}

### Edited to add explanations

Taking a small subset of `combinations` for demonstration:

```
testlist = combinations[[100 ;; 107]]

  (* {{0.817389, 0.231155, 0.396006}, {0.817389, 0.231155, 
  0.700474}, {0.817389, 0.231155, 0.211826}, {0.817389, 0.231155, 
  0.748657}, {0.817389, 0.231155, 0.422851}, {0.817389, 0.231155, 
  0.247495}, {0.817389, 0.231155, 0.977172}, {0.817389, 0.231155, 
  0.825163}} *)
```

This takes the intersection of each element of `testlist` with each of the three groups:

```
Table[Intersection[g, #], {g, groups}] & /@ testlist

  (* {{{0.817389}, {0.231155, 0.396006}, {}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155, 
   0.700474}, {}}, {{0.817389}, {0.211826, 
   0.231155}, {}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155, 
   0.748657}, {}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155, 
   0.422851}, {}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155, 
   0.247495}, {}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155}, {0.977172}}, {{0.817389}, \
{0.231155}, {0.825163}}} *)
```

When there is no intersection, the result is an empty list `{}`. Adding `/. {} -> Nothing` removes the empty lists.

```
temp = Table[Intersection[g, #] /. {} -> Nothing, {g, groups}] & /@ testlist

  (* {{{0.817389}, {0.231155, 0.396006}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155, 
   0.700474}}, {{0.817389}, {0.211826, 
   0.231155}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155, 
   0.748657}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155, 
   0.422851}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155, 
   0.247495}}, {{0.817389}, {0.231155}, {0.977172}}, {{0.817389}, \
{0.231155}, {0.825163}}} *)
```

Getting the length of each result (3 means the element of `testlist` at the same position had an intersection with all three groups):

```
ingroups = Length /@ temp

  (* {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3} *)
```

And the positions of `3`

```
pos = Position[ingroups, 3]

  (* {{7}, {8}} *)
```

This gets the elements of `testlist` at those positions

````
Extract[testlist, pos]

  (* {{0.817389, 0.231155, 0.977172}, {0.817389, 0.231155, 0.825163}} *)
```
````

Comment: This took 45.7 seconds to run, and the dimensions of 'answer' match what it should be. Would you mind explaining how this amazing piece of code works, please?

Comment: @LNah I added some explanations to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a brute-force approach that deals with the indices of `elements` first but is not as flexible as the answer from @MelaGo.  One advantage is that if there are several sets of `elements`, then the time consuming part which is getting the list of the positions only needs to be done once.

The `combinations` are the subsets with the `indices` rather than the `elements`.  Then a combination is selected if the minimum is less than 8 (to make sure Group 1 is represented), the maximum is greater than 14 (to make sure Group 3 is represented), and the absolute distance from 11 is less than 4 (to make sure Group 2 is represented.  (If there are more than 3 groups, then using the absolute distance of the midpoint of each group can be used as the metric to make decisions.)

```
elements = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 21];
indices = Range[21];
combinations = Subsets[indices, {3, 10}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 positions = Select[combinations, Min[#] < 8 && Max[#] > 14 && Min[Abs[# - 11]] < 4 &];
 answer = elements[[#]] & /@ positions;]
(* {5.2536641`,Null} *)

Length[answer]
(* 1001217 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### TL/;DR

```
SeedRandom[1];

elements = RandomReal[1, 21];

constrainedSubsets[Partition[elements, 7], Range[3, 10]] // 
   Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.765587, 1001217}
> ```

---

The function `constrainedSubsets`, defined below, generates the desired list of `1001217` constrained subsets directly rather than filtering `combinations`.

```
ClearAll[groupSubsets, groupCounts, constrainedSubsets]
```

The first helper function `groupSubsets[{group1,group2,..., groupm}, {n1,n2,...,nm}]` generates subsets of length $ n_1 + n_2 +\cdots+n_m$ containing exactly $n_i$ elements from $group_i$:

```
groupSubsets[grps_, gcounts_] /; And @@ Thread[gcounts <= Length /@ grps] := 
 Flatten[MapApply[Join] @ 
    Tuples @ MapThread[Subsets] @ {grps, List /@ gcounts}, {1}]
```

***Example:***

```
grps = {grp1, grp2, grp3} = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}};

highlight = MapThread[(a : Alternatives @@ # :> 
   Highlighted[a, Background -> #2]) &] @ {grps, {Red, Green, Yellow}};
```

Subsets of length `6` containing exactly `1` element from `grp1`, exactly `2` elements from `grp2` and exactly `3` elements from `grp3`:

```
groupSubsets[grps, {1, 2, 3}] /. highlight
```

[image]

For a list of groups (`groups = {group1, group2,..., groupm}` ) and a list of subset sizes (`sizes = {s1, s2,..., sk}`), the second helper function `groupSubsets[groups, sizes]` generates integer partitions $p_i$ of $s_i$ of length $m$ (where `m = Length @ {group1,...,groupm}`) with the constraint that each element of $p_i$ is greater than 1 and no greater than the size of $group_i$:

```
groupCounts[grps_, sLengths_] := Select[And@@Thread[# <= (Length /@ grps)] &] @
  Flatten[Permutations /@ 
    IntegerPartitions[#, {Length @ grps}] & /@ sLengths, 2];
```

***Example:***

```
grps =  {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}};

groupCounts[grps, Range[3, 5]]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 1},   
>   {1, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}
> ```

We combine `groupSubsets` and `groupCounts` to get a function that gives all subsets of a list of groups with lenghts in the list `sLengths`:

```
constrainedSubsets[grps_, sLengths_] := 
  Module[{gcounts = groupCounts[grps, sLengths]}, 
     Map[Splice @ groupSubsets[grps, #] &] @ gcounts]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];

elements = RandomReal[1, 21];

combinations = Subsets[elements, {3, 10}];


constrainedSubsets[Partition[elements, 7], Range[3, 10]] // 
   Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.765587, 1001217}
> ```

Subsets of `grps` with length 3 or 4 containing at least one element from each group:

```
Multicolumn[constrainedSubsets[grps, Range[3, 4]] /. highlight, 8]
```

[image]